# Reverse post columns in wordpress (not mobile responsive reverse)

Tags: wordpress, elementor, posts

I have multiple posts in wordpress (i'm using elementor also) and I want to reverse post columns when they are stacked in a template I created for this post to appear in a single page...

Example how it is now...
[image: Layout of what is happening]

What I want...
[image: Example of the layout I want]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just select the 2nd child with:

**article:nth-of-type(2n)**

and selects every pair element... *(you can also use it with the number u want)*

**FYI:** if you want to reverse-row the post elements you'll have to go deeper into the specificity, and you can even if you use a :nth selector in CSS...

This is the final css code:

```
.elementor-element-53dbac3 .elementor-widget-container .elementor-posts--skin-custom article:nth-of-type(2n) .elementor-2361 .elementor-section-wrap .elementor-section .elementor-container
{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```